# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with an ImageResizer plugin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, imageresizer

The extensions point page in the ImageResizer docs mention that plugins can "Modify http headers" but they don't have any direction or example on how to do so. I created a plugin that implements both the `IPlugin` and `IChache` interfaces to add the HTTP header but it doesn't feel right because:

1. I do NOT want to implement or create "an alternate caching system"
2. It does not work (the image does not display/displays as a blank image) if I do not include the code `current.RemapHandler(New NoCacheHandler(e))` at the end of the `Process()` method. I don't understand what this line is doing or the implications of remapping the handler

Here is my current implementation

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <resizer>
        <plugins>
            <add name="MyNamespace.CorsHeadersPlugin" />
            <add name="Watermark" />
            <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
            <add name="PsdReader" />
            <add name="WicDecoder" />
            <add name="WicEncoder" />
            <add name="WicBuilder" />
        </plugins>
    </resizer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

**CorsHeadersPlugin**

```
Imports ImageResizer.Caching
Imports ImageResizer.Configuration
Imports ImageResizer.Plugins
Imports ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic

Public Class CorsHeadersPlugin
    Implements IPlugin
    Implements ICache

    Private ReadOnly AllowedDomains As String()

    Public Sub New()
        AllowedDomains = {"http://allowthisdomain.com"}

#If DEBUG Then
        AllowedDomains = AllowedDomains.Union({"http://localhost", "https://localhost"}).ToArray
#End If
    End Sub

    Public Function CanProcess(current As HttpContext, e As IResponseArgs) As Boolean Implements ICache.CanProcess
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub Process(current As HttpContext, e As IResponseArgs) Implements ICache.Process
        Dim origin = current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)

        If AllowedDomains.Contains(origin) Then
            current.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        End If

        current.RemapHandler(New NoCacheHandler(e))
    End Sub

    Public Function Install(c As Config) As IPlugin Implements IPlugin.Install
        c.Plugins.add_plugin(Me)
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Function Uninstall(c As Config) As Boolean Implements IPlugin.Uninstall
        c.Plugins.remove_plugin(Me)
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handlers `ImageResizer.Config.Current.Pipeline.PreHandleImage and .PreHandleImageAsync` allow you to modify the response headers. Make sure to only register handlers once during AppStart.

Answer (score 0):

update, working implementation

```
Imports ImageResizer.Caching
Imports ImageResizer.Configuration
Imports ImageResizer.Plugins

Public Class CorsHeadersPlugin
    Implements IPlugin

    Private ReadOnly AllowedDomains As String()

    Public Sub New()
        AllowedDomains = {"http://allowthisdomain.com"}

#If DEBUG Then
        AllowedDomains = AllowedDomains.Union({"http://localhost:3416", "https://localhost:3416"}).ToArray
#End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Install(c As Config) As IPlugin Implements IPlugin.Install
        AddHandler c.Pipeline.PreHandleImage, AddressOf ModifyHttpHeaders
        c.Plugins.add_plugin(Me)
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Function Uninstall(c As Config) As Boolean Implements IPlugin.Uninstall
        RemoveHandler c.Pipeline.PreHandleImage, AddressOf ModifyHttpHeaders
        c.Plugins.remove_plugin(Me)
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub ModifyHttpHeaders(sender As IHttpModule, context As HttpContext, e As IResponseArgs)
        Dim origin = GetRequestOrigin(context.Request)

        If origin IsNot Nothing AndAlso AllowedDomains.Contains(origin) Then
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetRequestOrigin(request As HttpRequest) As String
        If request.Headers("Origin") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return request.Headers("Origin")
        ElseIf request.UrlReferrer IsNot Nothing Then
            Return request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```